# Record Detail page call card raw specific

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want documentation how can i define or use card in Laravel Nova like i have list of post and click on view icon i need to display count of comment like pie chart, for example

I have a list of posts with actions `view`, `edit` and `delete`, if I click on `view it should display a chart for the specific post.

Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: How about metrics? Check following link, https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/registering-metrics.html#resource-detail-metrics

Comment: You can call `->onlyOnDetail()` when registering `card`, similar to the example given in above link

Comment: Thanks @SauminiNavaratnam i will try these one